# Yii display correction in array values

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am creating simple form in Yii. In that, one field is Fav  sports and I've given multiple check boxes such as "Football","Cricket","Baseball". When I store these multiple data using json_encode(). It will store the records in database like: ["Football"],["Cricket"],["Baseball"]. 
When I try to display these records, it displaying as it is. I want to display it like "Football,Cricket,Baseball" without [] and " "

Comment: your json_encode must be like `["Football","Cricket","Baseball"]` and it will also saved it as in database

Comment: I got it but now I want to display it like " Football,Cricket, Baseball ". by removing [ ] and " " from record

Comment: use `CHtml::encode(trim($model->attribute, '[]'));`

Comment: Downvoted because you posted your question twice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221063/stored-data-cant-access-in-yii . Now do the correct thing and delete this question please.