# Stored data can't access in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have created form in Yii. In that I've created multiple check boxes.
 For Example: `Fav Sports= Football,Cricket,Baseball`
When I select all check boxes it will store records to database. For storing data I used `"json_encode($_POST['UserInfo']['sports']);"`. Then it will store data in this format `["Football"]["Cricket"]["Baseball"]`.

My question is when I go to update form page, all textfields or controls have have values but check boxes of fav sports remains unchecked because I can't able to access data that is `["Football"]["Cricket"]["Baseball"]`. How to access those records from database in Yii.

Comment: Please do not duplicate your questions. Instead, edit your question with new information you might have. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218081/yii-display-correction-in-array-values

Answer (score 0):

Your Model Override following Function as: -

```
public function beforeSave() {

    $this->sports = CJSON::encode($this->sports);
    return true;
}

public function afterSave() {

    $this->sports = CJSON::decode($this->sports, TRUE);
    return true;
}

public function afterFind() {
    $this->username = CJSON::decode($this->username, TRUE);
    return true;
}
```

In Your View

```
<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<div class="row">

<?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'sports', array('Football' => 'Football', 'Cricket' => 'Cricket','Baseball' => 'BaseBall')); ?>
</div>
```